# MBP with discrete graphics processor - can I use a dock to connect monitors?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, gpu

I have a 2019 Macbook Pro with an AMD Radeon Pro 5500M graphics processor plus Intel integrated graphics.
When I connect the laptop to a StarTech Triple Monitor USB 3.0 Docking Station that has 2 monitors (27" 2560x1440) connected to it, I see only the Intel integrated graphics being used.

use case: I'm trying to run X-plane 12. This complains it can't use the external monitors because they don't have enough available VRAM. The Radeon Pro 5500M has enough VRAM available, so the computer must be using the Intel integrated graphics to drive the external monitors.

Is it possible for the AMD Radeon Pro 5500M to control external monitors hooked up via a USB dock, or would I have to connect the monitors directly?

Comment: That’s not how GPU switching works; it’s by the application, not the location of the displays (external vs. internal).  See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202043

Comment: X-plane wants to use the Radeon. This succeeds when I'm only running the internal display, but fails when I've connected the dock with external displays.